# Axis width/thickness in ggtern

Tags: ggtern

A simple - and possible elementary - question that I have not been able to find an answer for:
How do I change/manage the axis width/thickness in ggtern?
Looks like the usual commands for that does not apply to ggtern
Help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance
Lars

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the new theme elements which are unique to ggtern, consider below some examples, which should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
library(ggtern)
base = ggtern() + theme_bw()

#All Axes
base + theme(tern.axis.line   = element_line(color='red',size=2))

#Individual Axes
base + theme(tern.axis.line.T = element_line(color='red',size=2))
base + theme(tern.axis.line.L = element_line(color='green',size=2))
base + theme(tern.axis.line.R = element_line(color='blue',size=2))
```

Comment: Thanks Nic - exactly what I was looking for :-)